# Joomla - how to move log in from home page to article page

Tags: joomla, module

http://www.linkmanagementgroup.com/

My problem is that i've got the log in on the Front Page (and homepage) but i need to move it so that it only appears with the "Link Associates" article page.

```
<div id="logIn">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />   
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />
<!--end of logIn--></div>
```

I edited the beez template to make it...if u haven't guessed!

Please help!

Cheeerrss,
Steph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Login module go the Module Manager and locate (select type = mod_login)see the pages it is enabled for.. then change selection to taste

note: it will only show items on your menus- so if it is only one content page you want it on - make sure that particular article is assigned to a menu (it can be any menu...even one that is not published...sometimes Joomla works in wacky ways)